# How to calculate a tx's effectiveGasPrice within a block?

Tags: transactions, gas-price, blocks

Let's say I query all transactions within a block. Assuming all transactions are already settled, how can I know what will be their `effectiveGasPrice` ?

I'm confused that transactions specify a `gasPrice` still, and it seem like it's often time the price paid by the transaction. I'm not sure how it's done.

EDIT: Knowing that I query the transactions from the block, and querying the receipt after, it seem that the gasPrice field is always the effectiveGasPrice.. Not sure why